# When creating an instance of a nested class, is an instance of the nesting class being made too?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance

When creating an instance of a nested class, is an instance of the nesting class being made too?

If not then the child only have access to static public (and protected) functions of the parent?

For example:

```
class a {
public:
    void baz();
    class b {
    public:
        void foo();
    };
};

int main(){ 
    a::b bar; //is an instance of a being made too?
    bar.foo();
}
```

Comment: You can't just change the question completely. I am reverting your edit.

Comment: I'm not changing it completely... I'm adding a point that I originally wanted to ask about, should I make another question instead? @juanchopanza

Comment: Yes, you should make another question. You shouldn't ask two questions in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points:

1. Adressing your question title, the answer is yes, a derived class always contains a subobject of its base class(es). I'd also prefer base class and derived class over parent class and child class, because of the "is-a" relationship. A derived class instance is a base class instance, but a child is not a parent.
2. Addressing your question body, you don't have parent/child or base/derived classes. The construct you have there is a class nested inside some other class. This is something completely different. Basically, this just creates a second class who's name is nested inside the other class' "namespace". Creating an instance of the nested class does not create an instance of the nesting class though.

Answer (score 2):

The "parent/child" terminology is commonly used to describe *inheritance* relationships, which your code doesn't have. Bearing that in mind, `b` doesn't have any data members or base classes of type `a`, so the answer is no. No object of type `a` is created.

Note that by virtue of being an inner class, `b` has access to  `a`'s non-public members.

```
void a::b::foo() {
  a obj;
  obj.some_private_member(); // OK
}
```

Comment: So it can access private member even if I give it another instance of `a` (not created in side the function)? And what do you mean? isn't `b` a child of `a` in my code?

Comment: @kuhaku I don't think C++ has an official definition for parent-child. But according to the commonly used definition, `b` isn't a child of `a`.

Comment: @kuhaku If the members are non-static, you need an object in order to access them.

Answer (score 1):

Class `b` is a member of class `a`. It is a nested type declaration. Neither subobject of this nested type is declared in the class `a`. So you may not call non-static member function `foo` because an instance of class `b` is required.

On the other hand, the definition of the nested class `b` does not include a subobject of class `a`. Any class has only those members that are declared inside the class definition.

So in this statement

```
a::b bar; //is an instance of a being made too?
```

there is created an instance of class `b` that according to its definition has only one member - member function `foo`

Answer (score -1):

The new parameters given in class b will be the same ones as "a" along with any additional parameters.

```
class a {  
        public:
           void bar();
        }

       class b : public a                            
       {
         public:
           void foo();
       }
```